# Get through a series of List<Object> lists

Tags: java, list, jaxb

If you have an object that has a `List<Object> list` whose elements themselves can refer to objects which also have a `List<Object> list`, whose elements themselves can refer to objects which also have a `List<Object> list`, and so on...and you want to get to an object of a specific type down in this structure.

What is the best way to achieve this?

My current approach is iterating through the first list, asking each element `obj.getClass() == XYZ.class`, if so, take the element, cast it, get it's `List<Object> list` and continue like before.

I am bound to these lists, because the classes were JAXB generated from XSD schemas.

All these iterations and castings are a huge mess and look not so clever...

Comment: I'm sure you can refactor your structure so that JAXB creates POJO instances instead of `List` objects.

Comment: Create a recursive function to go down the structure.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. With 'refactor your structure' you mean my XSDs? I'm afraid that's not possible because there are other applications (third party web services) which already use these excact XSDs and my application should support the same data structures like those existing applications. The XSDs were not made by me, I have no proper insight into them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this kind of recursive function:

```
public List<Test> getTestElements(List<Object> list) {
    List<Test> result = new ArrayList<Test>();
    for (Object o : list) {
        if (o instanceof Test) {
            result.add((Test) o);
        } else if (o instanceof List) {
            result.addAll(getTestElements((List<Object>) o));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It will return you a list of all Test object that are present in input list.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not use recursive function. It may cause Stackoverflow exception
2. Think your data structure is like a tree ( have nodes and child nodes). Use BFS (Breadth-first search) to traverse the tree and find and keep your matched object.
3. BFS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search
4. Use Java Queue to implement BFS.